# Why can we not edit less than 6 characters?

Tags: discussion, editing

When editing a question, you need to edit at least 6 characters. Typos can often be corrected with one or two characters. Why can we not edit less than six characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your edits require the approval of other members with higher reputation.  If you're only changing a few characters this is using up time of these other users for often trivial changes.  Once you have more reputation you will be able to make these edits.

See [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites), particularly the [answer by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/329733).